# Array behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

For some reason the code below yields unexpected behavior.

```
console.log(chartIntervals.length);
```

Displays '0' instead of the expected '10'.

```
console.log(chartIntervals);
```

Displays an array with 10 elements, and length 10.

```
console.log(chartIntervals[3]);
```

Displays 'undefined'.

I'm new to javascript. This is part of an angularJS controller. response.data.count is an integer part of a response from django API handled on another service file.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
    var getPriceChartCounts = function(filter) {
                var savedMinPrice = filter.priceMin;
                var savedMaxPrice = filter.priceMax;
                filter.priceMin = 0;
                filter.priceMax = 100000;
                var chartIntervals = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Properties.getByFilter(filter,Map.getMapBounds()).then(function(response){
                        chartIntervals.push(response.data.count);
                    });
                    filter.priceMin = filter.priceMin + 100000;
                    filter.priceMax = filter.priceMax + 100000;
                }

                filter.priceMin = savedMinPrice;
                filter.priceMax = savedMaxPrice;
                console.log(chartIntervals.length);
                console.log(chartIntervals);
                console.log(chartIntervals[3]);

                return chartIntervals;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chartIntervals is being populated *asynchronously*, as you can see by the `.then`. At the time you console.log it, the requests have only just been sent out - they haven't come back yet, so chartIntervals is still only an empty array, so its length is 0 and `chartIntervals[n]` for any `n` is undefined.

If you want your code to wait for the array to be populated before continuing, use `Promise.all`.